# Anchor animation in QML

Tags: animation, anchor, qml, qt5, qt-quick

How to get it to work anchors animation, like described here:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: container
    width: 200; height: 200

    Rectangle {
        id: myRect
        width: 100; height: 100
        color: "red"
    }

    Behavior on anchors.right {
        AnchorAnimation { duration: 2000 }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        myRect.anchors.right = container.right
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? There is no proper animation on changing anchors.

Also, if you can, provide some examples on this theme.

**UPD:** Provided simpler example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AnchorAnimation can only be used in a Transition and in conjunction with an AnchorChange. It cannot be used in behaviors and other types of animations.

from [AnchorAnimation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-anchoranimation.html) documentation. There you can also find an example how to use states to do AnchorAnimations.

Comment: Yes, sure, that is the answer. I'm ashamed about not noticing that moment in official documentation. I'll mark it as answered. But, don't you know how to deal with such kind of animation in `behavior`-way?

Comment: Jap, I think this one is answered. To be honest I have no clue about behaviors and transitions in detail since I don't use them very often. I was trying to find the mistake in your code and get it running. And it is not your fault that you didn't come across the proper documentation. Their Google ranking is horrible, since Qt was sold so often and each new version has it's own set of URLs. Try to add "qt5.1" to every Google search related to Qt.